# My BluetoothGattCallback() onCharacteristicChanged doesn't work below Android 13

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to receive data with a `BLE` device, but it doesn't work. I config my `onCharacteristicChanged` in this way:

```
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {

        bluetoothGatt.requestMtu(517)
    }

    override fun onMtuChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt, mtu: Int, status: Int) {
        val characteristic = findCharacteristics()

        enableNotification(characteristic)
    }

    fun ByteArray.toHexString(): String =
        joinToString(separator = "", prefix = "") { String.format("%02X", it) }

    override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        value: ByteArray
    ) {
        Log.d("CHAR", value.toHexString())
    }
```

Is only work in Android 13 when I run the app in Android 11 the `onCharacteristicChanged` doesn't trigger. The permissions that I check:

```
private fun checkPermissions() {
    when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            requestPermissions.launch(
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                )
            )
        }
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            requestPermissions.launch(
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

private val requestPermissions =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        permissions.forEach { (key, value) ->

            when (key) {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION -> {
                    if (!value) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            requireActivity(),
                            arrayOf(
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                            ),
                            1
                        )
                    }
                }
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT -> {
                    if (!value) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            requireActivity(),
                            arrayOf(
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                            ),
                            1
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When it runs on Android 11 the logs indicate that everything is working:

```css
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=7C:9E:BD:07:3D:82 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=7C:9E:BD:07:3D:82 Status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: configureMTU() - device: 7C:9E:BD:07:3D:82 mtu: 517
D/BluetoothGatt: onConfigureMTU() - Device=7C:9E:BD:07:3D:82 mtu=517 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00001103-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use this callback instead: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicChanged(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic). The overload you are trying to use where the value is passed as a parameter was added in Android 13 and hence does not work on older devices.

Comment: Yes, using the old onCharacteristicChanged works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Problem:

```
override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
    gatt: BluetoothGatt,
    characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
    value: ByteArray
)
```

This version of constructor is only  called when the device version is above android 12

Solution:

```
override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
    gatt: BluetoothGatt,
    characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic
)
```

Adding the old version of it the code worked normally